# How to get the data type of a std::any variable?

Tags: c++, stdany

```
std::any var = 1;
```

How can you get the type of `var`?

For example:

```
std::cout << GetTypeOf(var) << std::endl;
```

Output:

```
int
```

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any/type and https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info/name

Comment: Please do not apply the C tag to C++ questions.

Comment: I have tried std::cout << typeid(out).name() << std::endl; but it returns std::array

Comment: Note that `type_info::name` is implementation defined, it may or may not be `"int"`, but it is unlikely to be `"std::array"` unless there *is* and `std::array` of some sort in there. Please show a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
std::cout << var.type().name() << std::endl;
```

[Godbolt example](https://godbolt.org/z/EW6nsGaPq)

Note that the exact output of `name()` is implementation-defined, so you may get `i` instead of `int` for example.